# Footnotes don't show!

Tags: footnotes

Can someone help me out please? I am writing my cv, and I need a normal, standard footnote. Here is the heading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}


\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref} %make sure it comes last of your loaded packages
%\usepackage[dvips,bookmarks=false]{hyperref} %make sure it comes last of your loaded packages
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH,pdfhighlight=/O,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red,linkcolor=red}

\oddsidemargin = 21 pt
\evensidemargin = 21pt
\textwidth = 410 pt

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{Henrique GOMES\hspace{.5em}}
\chead{}
\rhead{Curriculum \hspace{.5em}   -- \hspace{.5em} Sep 2013}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{{Page \thepage ~of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}



\setlength\parindent{0in}
```

And the footnote is in a tabular environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
aaaa\footnote{aaaa}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please post something compilable instead of just sniplet.

Comment: Besides, footnotes does not belong inside tables. That is table notes, see `threeparttable` and the extension `threeparttablex`.

Comment: As Lars (aka. daleif) says, please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use footnotes in a CV? I wouldn't.

Comment: @egreg It depends on the footnote. A short one (a website URL for example, when it's relevant) is fine. Long ones, better not. :P

Answer (score 16):

It is quite difficult to use `\footnote` inside a floating environment, such as `{figure}` or `{table}`, because LaTeX can’t know where the float goes early enough to find out the right page for the footnotes. There are some ways to add a footnote, however.

### use a `{minipage}`

The `{minipage}` has it’s own footnotes an then the footnotes will flow together with you figure/table.

[image: minipage footnotes]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
document text
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            A & B\footnote{Text} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
document text
\end{document}
```

### help LaTeX by separating footnote number and text

You can set the footnote number with `\footnotemark` and then outside of the float the text with `\footnotetext{<Text>}`. In this case you must care thet the float environment and `\footnotetext` appear on the same page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
document text
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        A & B\footnotemark \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Text for the last footnote}
document text
\end{document}
```

But this will only work for a single pair of mark and text, i.e. you cant use two `\footnotemark`s without the `\footnotetext` for the first note *between* them.